# Restart ASP.NET Core App after Crash

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and learning.
Just want to know if there is a way to restart my app after the App Crashes?

Or is this kind of scenario handled different?

Couldnt find any Documentation on this, can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you host your ASP.NET Core application behind a full web server used as reverse proxy as IIS, it will get done automatically. IIS will receive a request and transmit it to your application, (re)launching it if necessary. You can check that great article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

On the contrary, if you use simply Kestrel (but it's not suitable for production really), Kestrel will stop and that's it, your app is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Apache on a Ubuntu 16.10 server.

Comment: I'm using IIS under Windows, but the logic should be the same, the full web server, Apache in your case, should act as a reverse proxy and handle your app, restarting it if necessary. I'm talking in theory though, I haven't tried, so if anyone has more input, could be interesting.

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy (see the lines Restart=always
    RestartSec=10                                          # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes)

Comment: Thanks that link seem prominising.

Answer (score 2):

When hosting your `ASP.NET Core` app as a `Windows Service` you can configure it to automatically restart if the service process terminates.

In your code, just do `Environment.Exit(1)` to terminate the process and then let the hosting environment restart it.

How this is configured in other environments I don't know, but I guess most hosts should have this configurable in some way. IIS probably do this allready.

However, this is only applicable to exceptions that do not allready kill your process. Exceptions on a request thread don't usually crash your app but you may want to take it down and restart in anyway, perhaps if you have in-memory state that may end up in a undefined and possibly hazardous way after an exception.